# css3 animation issue move div to left and move it back

Tags: html, css

i have following code to **move div into left**,

But what i want is to **move it to left and then again move it back**,,This should auto play..any idea??

```
 div
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    position:absolute;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 200px;}
    }



    @keyframes mymove {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 200px;}
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `animation-direction: alternate`. It will animate from the last keyframe value.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite alternate;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It would be better to add `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` to div CSS block

Comment: It does .Check it on webkit browser .It leaves trails of red on alternate motion.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py check this image -> http://i.imgur.com/ObXldtJ.png?1 .This doesnt happen on adding that property.

Comment: @Zword - Doesn't happen on my end. I've added it to my code though. Thanks for mentioning that. :)

Answer (score 1):

the following code should work

```css
div
     {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     background:red;
     -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
     animation: mymove 5s infinite;

     

     position:absolute;
     }

     @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
         0%   {left: 0px;}      
      50%  {left: 200px;}
      100% {left: 0px;}
     }



     @keyframes mymove {
         

         0%   {left: 0px;}      
      50%  {left: 200px;}
      100% {left: 0px;}
     }
```

```html
<div></div>
```